# Any symfony2 project tutorials for beginners?

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony2, Now I am working a symfony2 project, So I need some sample tutorials for creating websites using Symfony2 and xampp with mysql. No need any hello world type tutorials.

Comment: You can find the Jobeet Tutorial for Symfony 2 [here](http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/21/jobeet-tutorial-with-symfony2/) and [here](http://blog.quadspot.de/wordpress/symfony2/symfony2-tutorial-part-1-project-setup) is another tutorial for beginners The same question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354035/symfony-2-0-step-by-step-tutorial-required)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony 2.0 step by step tutorial required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354035/symfony-2-0-step-by-step-tutorial-required) (and there are so many more using search engine .....)

Answer (score 4):

I learned Symfony2 from the excellent [Symblog](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/) tutorial series. I found it remarkably in-depth and easy-to-follow.

Comment: This one I know before, I need more tutorials like this, Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to learn Symfony2 is, first reading a tutorial like Symblog or Joobet mentioned above and then fork a repo of one app on github which has been made with this framework and play with it. The symfony documentation will help you also.

There is a excellent book on www.symfony.es but is only in Spanish.