# Need to connect Facebook connect in Symfony2

Tags: facebook, symfony

I am new to Symfony 2 and want to integrate facebook Connect. Can anyone guide me step by step how to integrate facebook connect in Symfony2??

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354035/symfony-2-0-step-by-step-tutorial-required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look a the [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle), which does the job well, and has a good readme to set it up.